# Sum if data exists in range and matches on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have data in Google Sheets organized like so:

Sheet1:

```
Label     Type
foo       B
bar       A
baz       _(empty cell)
qux       B

totalX    quantity
totalY    quantity
```

Sheet2:

```
Type    X      Y
A       2      5
B       1      3
C       3      4
```

I would like 'quantity' in Sheet1 to sum type-associated values from Sheet2. In this example, `totalX` would be `4` (1+2+1, or Bx+Ax+Bx), and `totalY` would be `11` (3+5+3, or By+Ay+By).

Conceptually, the formula in `totalX` could look at each cell in 'Type' column on Sheet1, then if that cell is not blank it finds the value on Sheet2 and adds it to the total. After playing with `SUMIF` and various formulas, I can't manage to figure out how best to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2013/07/google-spreadsheet-advanced-vlookup-and.html:

To calculate **totalX**, if 'Label' and 'Type' are column A on their respective sheets:

```
 =sum(iferror(arrayformula(if(B2:B="";"";iferror(if(match(B2:B;'Sheet2'!A2:A4;0);vlookup(B2:B;'Sheet2'!A1:C4;{2}*sign(row(B2:B));false)))))))
```

And to calculate **totalY**:

```
 =sum(iferror(arrayformula(if(B2:B="";"";iferror(if(match(B2:B;'Sheet2'!A2:A4;0);vlookup(B2:B;'Sheet2'!A1:C4;{3}*sign(row(B2:B));false)))))))
```

Use `ISERROR` and `IFERROR` to ignore empty cells and cells that aren't found. `VLOOKUP` gets the actual values; `{x}*sign` references the appropriate column in Sheet2.